# Custom Solr FunctionQueries : Any good tutorial

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I'm looking to implement custom Solr FunctionQueries.

Are there are any good tutorials or step by step instructions, the only one i've found is http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html which doesn't explain the details well.

I do understand I need to implement `org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser` and `org.apache.solr.search.ValueSource`, but how does `public DocValues getValues(Map context, IndexReader reader)` work? How do i know the field value of a document inside this method and how do i compare it against the query?

I tried few books too but none have examples for implementing FunctionQueries.

Answer (score 0):

very old question but new to me.
I have found a sample project and not the step-by-step manual. but it's useful for the others.

[siterank sold custom query function](https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-siterank)

there is a custom function for Solr in this sample, which uses external tools/ services to provide a value.

Answer (score -2):

This tutorial is brief but gives a pretty good idea: http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html

Comment: the OP already mentioned the linked tutorial and found it lacking in detail.